# how to set the coordinates for a specific location on google earth that is integrated?

Tags: c#, google-earth

i integrated google earth in my C# form, i wanted to set the camera to 
the selected coordinate using the code, ge.setcameraparams(); , but 
after compiling with no errors, when i clicked the button that i had 
written the code, the program exits showing that i had invalid 
arguments. why is this so? 
this is my code:

```
private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     ge.SetCameraParams(1.3338139, 103.77629, 15.00, 0, 9.00, 10.00, 
 20.00, 1); 
}
```

is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
ge.SetCameraParams(1.3338139, 103.77629, 15.00, 
EARTHLib.AltitudeModeGE.RelativeToGroundAltitudeGE, 9.00, 10.00, 20.00, 1);
```

Comment: Do you know the meaning of this setting of EARTHLib.AltitudeModeGE.RelativeToGroundAltitudeGE. Thanks. Using EARTHLib.AltitudeModeGE.RelativeToGroundAltitudeGE make it work.